# Simple question about the heat equation (differential equations)

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

This is a question from my textbook.

The question is to find the temperature with the following information:
f(x) = 1
u(0,t) = 0
u(L,t) = 0
u(x,t) = f(x)

The equation itself:

[image: heat equation]

The solution from chegg:

[image: Answer from chegg]

From the circled line,
How did they get An = 0 from

[image]

A simple explanation would do. Thank you.

Comment: $\sin(n\pi)=\sin(0)=0$ for every $n $

Comment: sorry, it was a problem with wolfram. I didnt realize that sin(n*pi) = 0 everytime. Wolfram calculated sin(pi) in degrees.....

Answer (score 3):

$$
\left[\frac{1}{n}\sin (nx) \right]^\pi_0=\frac{1}{n}\sin(n\cdot \pi)-\frac{1}{n}\sin (n \cdot 0)=\frac{1}{n}\cdot 0 -\frac{1}{n}\cdot 0=0-0=0
$$

Comment: thank you. I realize my error. Wolfram calculated sin(n*pi) in degrees..... I feel like an idiot for wasting too much time on this

Answer (score -1):

We have that $\displaystyle \int_0^{π}\cos(x)\,dx=\int_0^{π}\cos(2x)\,dx.....=\int_0^{π}\cos(nx)\,dx=\boxed{0}$

Comment: Curious as to why this was down voted.